# Facebook PHP API Iframe applicaition

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, oauth, facebook-iframe

How can I get Authorization request answer inside Facebook Iframe application?
Authorization script written in PHP.
This is the authorization application request URL.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APPLICATIONID&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/example/?site=fb&response_type=code&scope=email,user_hometown
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you want to call the login dialog inside of an iframe? That is not possible, it has to be opened in the top window instance for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BY Using Facebook Api of php.Use this method

```
 $facebook->api('/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large)');
```